# PysimpleGui: pre-select an Item in a Combobox on Keyboard input

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have a GUI with pysimplegui that uses a combobox.
There are alphabetically sorted strings in the list for the combobox.

The Combobox is readonly (to only input the strings available),
so the user gets the drop down list right away when clicking anywhere on the combobox element.

When the drop-down list is open, the user can highlight items by the "up" and "down" keys.
Also selection of the highlighted item by the enter key is possible.

*It would increase the usability, if the highlight jumps to (or selects) the entry that starts with S when pushing the "s" key on the keyboard.*

**What I tried**

- opening the window with `return_keyboard_events=True` but it would not change the behaviour.
- Fiddeling with the `enable_per_char_events=True` for the combo element just shows that this method is no longer available in version 4.60.4 (though it is still in the [docs](https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/call%20reference/#combo-element)) and the code crashes.

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: You could try clicking on the options.

Comment: @SamuNemeth The idea is to use the keyboard to quikcly jump to elements in the list - and then use the mouse (or the enter key) to select the elements

Answer (score 1):

> 4.61.0.85
>
> Combo Element - new parameter enable_per_char_events.  When True will get an event when individual characters are entered.

Please upgrade your PySimpleGUI from Github.

Not all enhancements added into the PyPI version.
[Download from GitHub](https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/#upgrading-from-github-using-pysimplegui)

> There is code in the PySimpleGUI package that upgrades your previously pip installed package to the latest version checked into GitHub.
> You can use the commands `psgmain` to run the test harness or `psgupgrade` to invoke the GitHub upgrade code.

or, you can call `sg.main()`, like

```py
d:\>python
Python 3.10.2 (tags/v3.10.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PySimpleGUI as sg
>>> sg.main()
```

[image]

Following code demo another way by binding for it, but tkinter code required here.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

lst = sorted([
    'Global', 'USA', 'India', 'Brazil', 'Russian', 'France', 'UK', 'Italy',
    'Spain', 'Germany', 'Colombia', 'Argentina', 'Mexico', 'Turkey', 'Poland',
    'Iran', 'Ukraine', 'South Africa', 'Peru', 'Netherlands'])
width = max(map(len, lst)) + 2

font = ("Courier New", 16)
sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=font)

layout = [[sg.Combo(lst, size=(width, 5), key='COMBO'), sg.Button('Exit')]]
window = sg.Window("COMBO", layout, finalize=True)
combo = window['COMBO']
combo.bind('<Key>', ' Key')
combo.bind('<Enter>', ' Enter')
user_event = False

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    elif event == 'COMBO Enter':
        combo.Widget.select_range(0, 'end')
    elif event == 'COMBO Key':
        entry = values['COMBO'].lower()
        if user_event:
            user_event = False
        else:
            if entry:
                index = None
                for i, item in enumerate(lst):
                    if item.lower().startswith(entry):
                        index = i
                        break
                if index is not None:
                    user_event = True
                    combo.Widget.set(lst[index])
                    combo.Widget.event_generate('<Key-Down>')
                    combo.Widget.current(index)

    print(event, values)

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Thx Jason for the hint with the update.
Always assumed the PyPI package was up to date.

Comment: The code selects the first entry in the list when the input-cursor is in the combo box and the list not opened.
But when the list is open, it will not select any the entry as no event is issued.

Using 'enable_per_char_events' also does not generate an event when the list is open.

But arrow up / arrow down and enter keys do work to select items with the list being open.
Is this maybe a tkinter limit?

Comment: It depend on which element focused, entry or dropdown, then what action take. You can also refer https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Input_Auto_Complete.py for another different way.

Comment: Sorry, but the Demo is a totally different case (an input element with a listbox).
The demo sadly does not help. There is no event generated when the dropdown list is open and one pushes any key on the keyboard - so I can not execute a (filtering) function

Comment: Combobox is an input element with a listbox.

Comment: Then I am sorry for mixing terms.
I used the term "dropdown list" to describe the listbox which _magically_ appears when one clicks on an input element.
When you push a key on your keyboard, while the focus is in this "dropdown list", there is NO EVENT issued. Hence I can not apply any function to filter the list of items for the input list - or select an item based on the button that was pushed (.lower().startswith("a") or alike). Though no event issued, the interface detects keyboard inputs, as the "enter key" and the "up down arrow" keys cause a change or selection of the items.